# UILocalNotificationAction is not working after killing (completely closing ) the app

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

i implemented UILocalNotification on my app with a function and its working fine when the app is running in background but when i close the app completely then the notification appears but the function which is associated with didn't do anything , if anybody know what i did wrong or how to do it properly than help me

//AppDelegate.Swift//

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {







    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    //set up Notifications//

    //actions
    //actions for notifications//
    let firstAction:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    firstAction.identifier = "FIRST_ACTION"
    firstAction.title = "Yes"

    firstAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    firstAction.destructive = false
    firstAction.authenticationRequired = false


    let secondAction:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    secondAction.identifier = "SECOND_ACTION"
    secondAction.title = "No"
    secondAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    secondAction.destructive = true
    secondAction.authenticationRequired = false

    // category
    let firstCategory: UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    firstCategory.identifier = "FIRST_CATEGORY"

    let defaultActions:NSArray = [firstAction, secondAction]
    let minimalActions:NSArray = [firstAction, secondAction]

    firstCategory.setActions([firstAction, secondAction], forContext: .Default)
    firstCategory.setActions([firstAction, secondAction], forContext: .Minimal)

    //NSSET Of all Our Category
    let categories:NSSet = NSSet(objects: firstCategory)

    //asking  permission for notifcation
    if #available(iOS 8, *){
        let mySettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge], categories: categories as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(mySettings)


        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    }

    return true
   }


func increaseScore(){


    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let proxy = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Proxy", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    proxy.setValue(1, forKey: "present")
    proxy.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "date")



    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
    print(proxy)
    print("Object Saved")
  }




// handling actions
func application(application: UIApplication,
    handleActionWithIdentifier identifier:String?,
    forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification,
    completionHandler: (() ->Void)){

        if(identifier == "FIRST_ACTION" ){
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionOnePressed", object: nil)
        } else             if(identifier == "SECOND_ACTION" ){
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionTwoPressed", object: nil)
        }

        completionHandler()
}
```

//ViewController.Swift//

```
     // setting notfication action
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "increaseScore", name: "actionOnePressed", object: nil)
    //scheduling notification
    let dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComp.year = 2015;
    dateComp.month = 11;
    dateComp.day = 02;
    dateComp.hour = 22;
    dateComp.minute = 50;
    dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
    let date:NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!

    let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
    notification.alertBody = "hey been to college? "
    notification.fireDate  = date
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

    let dateNow = NSDate()
    let noticalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let hour = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: dateNow)

    if    isalerViewShown == false  && hour >= 15   {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }}
```

Comment: What method does the ViewController.swift code exist in?

Comment: what method ? @CharlesA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle local notifications when your app is not open you must inspect the launch options dictionary in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  The local notification is delivered to you in this dictionary.

According to [the documentation for `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:):

> If the user chooses to open the app when a local notification occurs, the launch options dictionary passed to the application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods contains the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey key. This method is called at some point after your delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Here is an example of how one might handle local notifications in a general sense:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: "A notification was received while the app was not running, and the user launched the app", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: "A notification was received while the app was running", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    var window: UIWindow?
}
```

Comment: okay so the codes which are in ViewController i have to put them in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: this ?

Comment: Whatever action you want to take in response to a local notification, you need to do in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` if there is a local notification present in the `launchOptions` dictionary.

Comment: okay @CharlesA  thanks you're helping me and sorry i am asking dumb questions but can you give me an example because am not too familiar with this meaningful words

Comment: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]  this will able to work while app is not running ,  right ?

Comment: If the user chooses to launch your app from the notification, then your app is launched and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is invoked.  If the user does not choose to open your app from the notification, it will not happen.

Comment: but i don't want to open the app, there's a function which i want to execute without opening the app @charlesA

Comment: This is not possible with local notifications.  Apple only allows for limited background execution modes (as discussed in [the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)) and there is no background execution mode for local notifications.